# Retrieving larger user photos from the Google Admin SDK

Tags: google-admin-sdk

I've been looking at retrieving photos for every user in a given domain using the Google Admin SDK. I've been able to do this using a request to get all users in the domain using the instructions from

`https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-users#get_all_domain_users`

and then doing a separate call using the instructions from

`https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-users#get_photo`

to retrieve their photo. The problem I'm having now is that the photos coming from this are too small for me to use.

The domain, as is, does not use Google+ and I've been told that's not an option. Is there an alternative - either a combination of other Google APIs or changing something (e.g. the use of `/thumbnail` in the `User.photo` API) in the current API calls - which would give me a larger quality image?

Comment: Is this the photo you are getting from users.photos.photoData?

Comment: Yeah, so far I've just been decoding it and saving it to disk. It's coming out at 96px.